# How to use angular to populate the select drop down list from an object withing an object.

Tags: angularjs

I have the following JSON Object

```
 $scope.items = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Red',sizes:[{size:'s'},{size:'b'}]  },
    { id: 2, name: 'Green',sizes:[{size:'s'},{size:'b'}]   },
    { id: 3, name: 'Yellow',sizes:[{size:'s'},{size:'b'}]   }];
```

I'm trying to create a select option like the one below

```
<select id="s1" >
    <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Red S">Red S</option>
    <option value="Red b">Red b</option>
    <option value="Green S">Green S</option>
    <option value="Green b">Green b</option>
    <option value="Yellow S">Green S</option>
    <option value="Yellow b">Green b</option>

</select>
```

Is it possible to achieve this using ng-options, if not what are my other options using angular.

Comment: Your options are well explained in the docs : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything is possible with Angular ;)  But for something like this (the data in that shape), using option groups would be your only option.  To display them as a straight list of options as you showed, you would have to flatten your object first, and then do a ng-options on the new object/array.

```
<select id="s1" ng-model="selected">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup ng-repeat="item in items" label="{{item.name}}">
      <option ng-repeat="size in item.sizes">{{item.name + ' ' + size.size}}</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Check out this [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QGrv0wrC047fagVhRKvm?p=preview).